# Reload only one variable in loop()

Tags: lcd

I need some information for the TFT screen 2.8 and arduino mega.
The screen works very well and displays the data.
The small problem I encounter is for the text display, the page is reloading every second and this makes a small black screen every second.
I would like to know if it was possible to reload only one part of the screen display?

See in video
https://youtu.be/vxSa6xkH0vU

My `loop()`

```
void loop(void) {
   tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setRotation(3);
  dt = clock.getDateTime();
  clock.forceConversion();

  // Go 
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextColor(GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(5);
  tft.println("Info");
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println(clock.dateFormat("d-m-Y H:i:s", dt)); 
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Temperature: ");
  tft.println(clock.readTemperature());

  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: Don't do a `fillscreen` when you don't need to.

Comment: @ratchetfreak When i remove `fillScreen` this generates a dual display :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tft.rect(x,y,width,height)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/TFTRect) to clear only a portion of the screen. Make sure to set `tft.fill` before calling it.